# Cannot resolve method intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on an Android Tutorial, which Authenticates with an ASP.Net Web API, using Identity. I have run across a problem I can't seem to fix.

I have an Intent that keeps giving me an error, and I don't know why it is giving me this error in Android Studio, The code from the MainActivity is below.

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
   ValueActivity.intent(MainActivity.this).accessToken(result.getAccessToken()).start();
}
```

Here is the ValuesActivity

```
@EActivity(R.layout.value)
public class ValueActivity extends ListActivity {
String[] values;

@Extra("AccessToken")
String accessToken;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.value);
}

@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    new GetValuesTask().execute();
}


class GetValuesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", accessToken)));

        JSONHttpClient httpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
        values = httpClient.GetWithHeader(ServiceUrl.VALUES,headers,new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(),String[].class );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ValueActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

}

If I am calling an intent method shouldn't the intent method by in the values activty, I mat be wrong.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: I have never seen that syntax for an intent... And there is no intent variable, so it is not clear what you expect to happen there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those annotations must be for some library...

Try using standard Android API code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ValueActivity.class);
i.putExtra("AccessToken", result.getAccessToken());
startActivity(i);
```

Or, you seem to be needing to read about the [AndroidAnnotations - Intent Builder](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks#intent-builder)

No guarantees this works, but you are missing the underscore

```
ValueActivity_.intent(MainActivity.this).accessToken(result.getAccessToken()).start();
```